# Procedure or function expects parameter, which was not supplied. A nullable column throwing exception

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am creating/updating a record in sql db with a stored procedure. I am supplying around 30 parameters from my C# Data Access Layer. sql table has all the columns null able apart from its primary key column. here when i supply a null value to a null able column, it is throwing an exception of "Procedure or function 'spFullUpdate' expects parameter '@App1TAPAYears', which was not supplied.". In my c# code I can clearly see the column is supplied with a null value. Could please anyone tell me how I can rectify this issue.
Following is my code snippet.
Setting value to the data object is as follow

```
Dt.TimeAtPreviousAddressYears = int.TryParse(TimeatPreviousAddressYears.Text, out intOut) ? intOut : (int?)null;
```

following is the nullable property in my entity class

```
        public int? TimeAtPreviousAddressYears { get; set; }
```

My data access layer adding parameter code is as follow

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@App1TAPAYears", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dataObject.TimeAtPreviousAddressYears;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It can clearly be seen that the parameter is added and null value is supplied to a null able column but it still producing exception. Anyone's help will really be appreciated.

Kind Regardds

Comment: Please show the code where you add all the parameters until you execute the SP. ( Edit your post )

Comment: the code is fine as it doesn't produce exception when i supply a value to this parameter. Exception only raised when the value is null.

Comment: just wanted to be sure. Have seen to much questions about parameter not supplied which has been caused by creating the command object again just before the query.

Comment: In my case command parameter is created successfully. The problem is with the null value.

Comment: In command parameter list, the IsNullable property of @App1TAPAYears is coming as set to false and Value is 'null'.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`nullable != DBNull.Value`

So you can't pass `(int?)null` to the parameter value but instead pass `DBNull.Value`

Like:

```
if (dataObject.TimeAtPreviousAddressYears.HasValue) 
{ 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@App1TAPAYears", SqlDbType.Int).Value =dataObject.TimeAtPreviousAddressYears;
}else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@App1TAPAYears", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: I m getting an error of 'Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int?' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: So this `shortcircuit` or however this assignment is named won`t work in this case so you need to use the classic if else. Updated my answer.

Comment: This fixed my problem, but only because in my stored proc I had `@paramname int NULL` instead of `@paramname int = NULL` d'ohh. With the equals-sign you can pass in `null` from C# all day long.

Answer (score 7):

This is a really annoying problem, which threw me out recently because I'd not come across it for a long time.

I settled on adding this in my RepositoryBase class

```
    protected object ValueOrNull(object value)
    {
        return value ?? DBNull.Value;
    }
```

and this this in my actual repo code for any optional items

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VoucherCode", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = ValueOrNull(promo.VoucherCode);
```

Comment: Or with slightly more markup but no extra method:  `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VoucherCode", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = (object)Value ?? DBNull.Value;`

Answer (score 1):

You should try with

```
if (dataObject.TimeAtPreviousAddressYears.HasValue) 
{ 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@App1TAPAYears", SqlDbType.Int).Value =dataObject.TimeAtPreviousAddressYears;
}else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@App1TAPAYears", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (object)DBNull.Value;
}
```

The issue is that (as the error message indicates) the conditional expression needs  identical types on both branches.